# Python Negative time difference

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I want to calculate the total time. My model counts the time difference - and stores, the view counts the time sum.
It works. But if the time difference is negative(01:00 - 21:00), then I get an error(time data '-1 day, 4:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'). according to the idea it should be 4:00 o'clock I suppose that you need to save time not explicitly, but I do not understand how to do it. Or do you need to use something else?

Models.py

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    ...
    start_work = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Начало работы')
    finish_work = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Окончание работы')
    hours_worked = models.CharField(verbose_name='Отработано часов', max_length=50, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def hours_work(self):
        result = datetime.combine(date.today(), self.finish_work) - datetime.combine(date.today(), self.start_work)
        hours_work1 = str(result).rsplit(':', 1)[0]
        hours_worked = hours_work1
        return hours_worked

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs, ):
        self.hours_worked = self.hours_work
        super(Trip, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

wiews.py

```
total_time = timedelta(hours=0, minutes=0)
me = trip.values_list('hours_worked')
sum_hour = 0

for el in me:
    for i in el:
        time = datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S")
        t1 = timedelta(hours=time.hour, minutes=time.minute)
        total_time = total_time + t1
        sum_hour = str(total_time).rsplit(':', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute the total hours in a `datetime.timedelta` object, which is what you get when you compute the difference between to `datetime.datetime` objects, you can use `total_seconds`:

```
td = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 15)

total_hrs = td.total_seconds() // 3600
```

I don't get why you can't do directly `self.finish_work - self.start_work` ? And also how can that be a negative number? You cannot finish working one day before starting, so I assume, that your code has an issue. Probably in the use of `datetime.combine` where a job is started at 16:00 on day X and finished at 1:00 on day X + 1. For your code the start and finishing dates will be the same and only the hour will change, giving you the negative difference.

Comment: directly `self.finish_work - self.start_work` throws an error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time .I only use time, no date. Here you are right if the work started today at 12:00 and will finish tomorrow at 13:30, then the result will not be correct. Logically, the work cannot exceed more than 24 hours, therefore there is no date binding.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be solved. Added a condition: `if self.finish_work < self.start_work:` add 24 hours

```
def hours_work(self):
        if self.finish_work < self.start_work:
            time = datetime.combine(date.today(), self.finish_work) + timedelta(hours=24)
            result = time - datetime.combine(date.today(), self.start_work)
        else:
            result = datetime.combine(date.today(), self.finish_work) - datetime.combine(date.today(), self.start_work)
        hours_work1 = str(result).rsplit(':', 1)[0]
        hours_worked = hours_work1
        return hours_worked
```